# Item disappear after filter

Tags: reactjs

Here's my filter code:

Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-stonebraker-9i460b?file=/src/App.js

```
const [CurrentMovieCard, setCurrentMovieCard] = React.useState("All");

const handleBtns = (e) => {
    let word = e.target.value;
    setCurrentMovieCard(word);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (CurrentMovieCard === "All") {
      setMovieItem(data);
    } else {
      const filtered = data.filter((card) => {
        // you have categories as strings and array of strings
        return (
          card.genre === CurrentMovieCard ||
          (card.genre.includes(CurrentMovieCard) &&
            card.cinema === CurrentMovieCard) ||
          card.cinema.includes(CurrentMovieCard)
        );
      });
      setMovieItem(filtered);
    }
  }, [CurrentMovieCard]);
```

`

I don't quite understand how come my item will disappear after filtering. Please help!

Comment: Please share the `code` for `rendering` and explain what is disappearing after filtering.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can use codesnadbox or others online editor to share link, that can show the problem more clearly.

Comment: I've added the link already.

Comment: @obeselizard, Try changing the filter array from `movieItem` to `data` like, `const filtered = data.filter((card) => { .. })`

Comment: Before it was data, I changed it to movieItem because I assume it will display the newly added item and deleted ones. It still didn't work :(

Comment: @obeselizard, Can you check here and let me know what was the exact issue? https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-morning-fnx0o3

Comment: @ManirajMurugan I don't see any genre filter anymore.

Comment: @obeselizard, In your sandbox, there is no content inside genre component.

Comment: @ManirajMurugan there is, under GenreButtons.js.

Comment: @obeselizard, File is there but content is not there. Please run your codesandbox you will get the error bcoz your `GenreButtons.js` is empty.

Comment: @ManirajMurugan Odd, it shows for me. Here's the code btw
https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-stonebraker-9i460b?file=/src/GenreButtons.js:0-933

Comment: @obeselizard, Okay now its working. Can you provide more detail exactly what the issue was? If I click any genre like Horror, Action, etc.., data are displaying correctly.

Comment: @ManirajMurugan oh great! I want it to also display the newly added movies because I don't think it's reflecting. The deleted ones too :(

Comment: @MOLLY I've updated the link already.